# ClassNotFoundException when running hadoop/mapReduce

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce

In my MapReduce project, I use the apache-commons CSVParser to parse a CSV file line by line and extract the fields I am interested in.

I use Maven in Eclipse to import the dependencies, and use eclipse to export the project as a jar file.The jar file includes all the dependencies. I am curious why hadoop still throws the following exception:

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser

I'm on a Windows machine, is there any other better ways of making jar files?

Answer (score 0):

First you can put your CSV jars into class path and compile your mapreduce job class. If it compile correctly than While running the mapreduce job, also add this jar in hadoop command.